# Spring data jpa save

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

How can I pass the test? (was working before migrate my code to use repositories). The `bs` are stored in the database after save, but the object are not updated. What I have to do to achieve it?

Given these classes:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
   private Set<B> bs= new HashSet<B>();
   ...
}

@Entity
public class B {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   private String aId;
   private String foo;
   ...
}
```

And Repository:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = A.class, idClass = String.class)
public interface ARepository {
   ...
   void save(A a);
   ...
}
```

This test fail:

```
    // "a" saved and flushed
    B b = new B();
    b.setAId(a.getId());
    a.getBs().add(b);
    ARepository.save(a);
    assertTrue(b.getId() > 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repository.save()`  does `persist` (if the provided argument is transient) or `merge` (otherwise).

Since `a` is not transient, `merge` is performed, meaning that there is no `persist` operation that could be cascaded to `bs`.

You either have to save `b` explicitly or add `b` to a new `a` before the `a` is saved, so that `persist` is cascaded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the reason is that B object is not in persisted state yet. As soon as it will be saved - you shouldn't get errors.

Should look like this:

```
// "a" saved and flushed
B b = new B();
BRepository.save(b)
b.setAId(a.getId());
a.getBs().add(b);
ARepository.save(a);
assertTrue(b.getId() > 0);
```

Also could you please provide stacktrace? Would be really helpful.

Comment: before using `session.save` I didn't have to save the object separately to get the Id, there isn't a way to persisted B?, there is not stackTrace, the assert fail.

Comment: I see, I actually recreates your test and everything works fine. The only difference that I'm creating repository like this:

`public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, String>{}`

Could you please provide your configuration?